# debian zero cpu usage on process stat

Tags: linux, debian

I use debian linux debian 6 (Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 on x86_64) and if I query the process stat list (ps or top) every process has zero cpu usage. If I query the apache stat there is also zero cpu usage.

I have installed every upgrade package but the problem is still on.
And I forgot to mention that the server has load. So the cpu usage mustn't be zero!

This is a HP server with SAS RAID1, 12GB ram and one Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5504 @ 2.00GHz, 4 cores. (not virtual)

I think there must be some missconfigure or some file has damaged or something. I'm not linux specailist so I don't know what can cause this.

Comment: Is your server actively receiving requests or is it idle?

Comment: No it isn't idle it has load. The apache example has average 5-10 request / sec and the mysql has load too. So the cpu usage must be over zero. Average 5-10 process queue for the cpu. The problem that because I can't see the cpu usage at the process list I can't analyze which process uses too much cpu.

Comment: Is this a virtual server?

Comment: no this is not it is a dedicated server what serves one online travel agency website.

Comment: Try the "show threads as processes" option, which I think is the "H" option to ps.

Comment: thanks for the idea but it doesn't show the cpu usage too. Every row in the stat is 0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server has freezed and I had to restart it. After the restart the cpu usage showing is working in the top and in the ps util too.
I don't know what was wrong but the restarting solved it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a virtual server problem. If you are using VMware make sure vmware tools are installed and running.

Vmware might not be allocating cpu time to it and that is basically the only thing I can think of that could cause this discrepancy. If you are using vmware, reinstall vmware tools and run vmware-config-tools.pl etc

Comment: sorry but this is a dedicated server with no virtualization enabled.

Comment: There is a huge difference between a VPS and a VM, and I think your server may be the latter--i.e., it is your server, a single host, but it is hosted on a large server designed for running multiple VMs.  Being unable to read CPU stats would be a serious issue that would be extremely difficult to explain otherwise--and often times, the simplest answer is the right one. :)